# Eclipse Link Exceptions while deploying CXF based Web application

Tags: web-services, weblogic, cxf, classloader, weblogic12c

I have a Weblogic 10.3.5 with Java 1.6.0_24 on a Windows machine. I use CXf 2.2.3 for managing the web service components
Recently,started upgrading to Weblogic 12.1.1 with JDK 1.7.0_13. But the application does not get deployed with the new configuration

The stack trace is added below and the complete log of the stack trace is attached herewith for reference
XXXX is an instance variable and YYYY is a domain class. The domain class does not have a instance variable by the name XXXX

javax.xml.bind.JAXBException:

### Descriptor Exceptions:

Exception [EclipseLink-59] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The instance variable [XXXX] is not defined in the domain class [YYYY], or it is not accessible.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: XXXX
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping[XXXXX]

### Runtime Exceptions:

- with linked exception:
  [Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException

### Runtime Exceptions:

```
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:535)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:476)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:435)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:676)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.login(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:634)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.<init>(XMLContext.java:830)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.<init>(XMLContext.java:770)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext.<init>(XMLContext.java:177)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:860)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:830)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:143)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:142)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.db.toplink.JAXBContextFactory.newContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:180)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.create(BindingContextFactory.java:179)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:211)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:185)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:184)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:109)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:321)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:99)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:74)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:58)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:130)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:411)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:232)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:546)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:525)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:601)
            at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.getEndpoint(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:183)
            at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.registerEndpoint(JAXWSServlet.java:139)
            at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.init(JAXWSServlet.java:68)
            at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.init(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:54)
            at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:299)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:250)
            at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
            at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
            at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:94)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:82)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:74)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:60)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:34)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:624)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:565)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1848)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1738)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2740)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1704)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:781)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
            at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:212)
            at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:111)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
            at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
            at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
            at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
            at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
            at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
            at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:582)
            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:335)
            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
            at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
            at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
            at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
            at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

To resolve this exception i tried to load the geronimo_ws_metadata_2.0.jar that is present in my application instead of weblogic implementation by adding javax.jws.* package into weblogic-application.xml. That led to one more exception

ServletException: Servlet class: does not implement javax.servlet.Servlet

After some readings found the below link

(https://devwebcl.blogspot.in/2012/05/filtering-classloading-failing-with.html)
[Weblogic Link](https://devwebcl.blogspot.in/2012/05/filtering-classloading-failing-with.html)
which says we could not add javax.* or java.* for class loader filtering from Weblogic 12.1.1 onwards. Hence I had to revert the changes.
Now I am stuck with the initial exception.